# Combining two lists of different object types and sorting the combined list

Tags: java, android

I am trying to combine two lists of different objects for simplicity ill refer to them as `List<A>` and `List<B>` and in the end sort the combined list by their date value. I've seen most of the answers here but they dont show the whole picture on how to properly implement such use case.

I have created an inferface with a `String getDate()` method. So that my `Class A` and `Class B` both imeplement said interface.

```
 public interface CustomInterface {

    String getDate();

}
```

Then i have created a CustomComparator class:

```
    public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<CustomInterface> {
    
     @Override
     public int compare(CustomInterfacet1, CustomInterface t2) {
        return t1.getDate().compareTo(t2.getDate());
     }
    }
```

I also implemented a custom class which handles both the merge and sorting of the two given Lists.
We will call it `Class Merge`. With the method implemented below.

```
public List<Object> sortedAndMergedData(List<A> a, List<B> b) {

    List<Object> x= new ArrayList<>();
    x.addAll(a);
    x.addAll(b);
    Collections.sort(x, new CustomComprator());
    return x;

}
```

This is where the issue is, because im getting an error, "reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Object conforms to Interface" on  `Collections.sort(x, new CustomComprator());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `List<Object>` to  `List<CustomInterface>` in

```
List<Object> x= new ArrayList<>();
```

provided that both your `A` and `B` classes `implements CustomInterface`

```
public List<CustomInterface> sortedAndMergedData(List<A> a, List<B> b) {

    List<CustomInterface> x= new ArrayList<>();
    x.addAll(a);
    x.addAll(b);
    Collections.sort(x, new CustomComprator());
    return x;

}
```

Comment: But wouldnt that mean that the only objects i would have access to are those defined in interface? so i.e when i want to print data from this new sorted list i only have access to getDate?

Comment: But `A` and `B` class are implementing the same interface, I don't get your comment. Moreover in your code where `List<Object>` it is impossible to even call `getDate`. If you want to explicitly call a method of lets say class `A` that doesnt exist in class `B` you have to check if the item of `List<CustomInterface` is `instance of` class `A` then cast it to `A` and call it's method.

Comment: Aye i figured it was written poorly sorry for that. This solved my issue thank you, marked your answer as completed.